# Extracting token and parameterizing in another request

Tags: karate

I get a JSON response from a Post request

```
{
    "access_token": ".u9H5YgCCoMJHTW6SgVMxJe2aUEGHpMBbUf1456Gkj28",
    "token_type": "bearer",
    "expires_in": "4319",
    "scope": "READ "
}
```

I want to take this access token and pass it in another GET API request as the following.

```
And header Authorization = token
```

what i did ? 
first post api

```
* def response.access_token = token 
Given url ''
And header Authorization = token
```

This is not working

Answer (score 1):

I think you got confused with the syntax, both the below will work:

```
And header Authorization = response.access_token
```

or:

```
* def token = response.access_token
And header Authorization = token
```